# Unable to set a default image conditionally based on ThisItem value

Tags: powerapps

I'm using SQL Server IMAGE field type to store an image for a record.  I set the Image attribute like so:

`If(IsBlank(ThisItem.VisitorImage), 'full+pink+stroke+small+cropped (1)', ThisItem.VisitorImage)`

If I set the image just to 'full+pink+stroke+small+cropped (1)' it works fine, so the image reference itself is fine.  But none of my records have an IMAGE value yet, the database just shows null, and I want to display a default.  How can I check for a blank/null IMAGE to display a default?

This also doesn't give me what I want.

`Coalesce(ThisItem.VisitorImage, 'full+pink+stroke+small+cropped (1)')`

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to check, in Power Apps, if a SQL Server image is null (I'll create a bug with the product team to fix that). There are a couple of options you have:

- Add a second image control with the 'full+pink+stroke+small+cropped (1)' image, and reorder it so that it lies *behind* the image control with the actual image; if there is no image in the row, then it won't show anything, and the backup image will be shown.

  - This may not work well if the image has transparent pixels
- Add a new column in the SQL table, that tells whether it has an image or not. Something along the lines of `ALTER TABLE <tableName> ADD HasVisitorImage AS IIF(VisitorImage IS NULL, 0, 1)`, and use this new column to choose whether to show the original or backup image: `If(ThisItem.HasVisitorImage, ThisItem.VisitorImage, 'full+pink+stroke+small+cropped (1)')`

Comment: In addition to Carlos, IMAGE columns will be retired in a future update of SQL Server so it’s best to already find a good solution like storing the images in blob and the data in SQL